# "mind-numbing" can be meant "extremely shocking"?

Tags: word-meaning

In "Inherit the Stars" there is a expression like this:

> The mind-numbing impact of Caldwell's revelations had by this time abated sufficiently for him to begin putting together in his mind something of a picture of what it all meant.

The definition of "mind-numbing" in the dictionary is only "extremely boring". But in this sentence the meaning is opposite.

I can understand that when we get shocked the mind become kind of numb.
Is it common usage that "mind-numbing" as a "extremely shocking"?

Comment: I wonder if the author had meant to convey [_mind-blowing_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mind-blowing).

Comment: @J.R. That would certainly be a clearer way of saying it, assuming that that was its intended meaning.

Comment: Per Collins dictionary: "so bad, boring, or great in extent that you are unable to think about it clearly".  Like some prose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind-numbing can also be interpreted quite literally as numbing of the mind.  In other words, a mind-numbing event does not just shock you, it dazes and confuses you as well at least in this context.

So this sentence is simply stating that the shock of Caldwell's revelations had lifted enough to begin understanding what it all meant.

I can certainly understand how that might be a confusing double-meaning.  "Mind-numbing" isn't really used often enough to be considered common in usage one way or the other.  It is encountered more often than not in literature.